# SQL Incorrect Syntax near keyword

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert value 1 to the column isLogged, but it must be on the same row of the player using it.

```
string checkUserLogStatusQuery = "INSERT INTO [playerInfo] (isLogged) VALUES (1) WHERE PlayerName ='" + checkPlayerName + "'";
```

I'm getting incorrect syntax near keyword WHERE
What would the right syntax be?

Comment: You may looking for Update Command -> `UPDATE  [playerInfo] SET isLogged=1 WHERE PlayerName ='" + checkPlayerName + "'"`

Comment: "INSERT" is not "insert column value into *existing* record", but "insert entirely *new* record into table". You want "UPDATE" which means "update column(s) in existing record(s)".

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT` inserts a record, so a `WHERE` is pointless. You want to use `UPDATE`:

```
string checkUserLogStatusQuery = "UPDATE [playerInfo] SET isLogged = 1 WHERE PlayerName = @PlayerName"; // always use parameterized queries
```